# WP_Remote_Get Not working

Tags: functions, core, wp-remote-get

I have a plugin which uses `wp_remote_get()` and it's not working on my nginx server so I decided to test this.

I created a file called `test.php` and inserted:

```
<?php $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.domain.com/mytest.php' );

print $response ['body']; ?>
```

When I run this file I am getting error:

```
2017/02/04 16:22:31 [error] 16573#16573: *461100 FastCGI sent in stderr:
…

 "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
 wp_remote_get() in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/x-child/test.php:1
```

I cannot tell why this would be undefined function, given that its part of wordpress core?

Comment: Are you running this from a WP "cron" job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very concept of HTTP API is to make sure transport will be done. It basically uses 5 different transport methods and it chooses the best one according to your server config. So it's unlikely a compatibility issue with `wp_remote_get()` and your server.

Plus if WP is not loaded, adding an action won't help, it will fail the same with undefined function error but this time on `add_action`.

So basically you're missing WordPress, for test purpose you could do this (assuming your file is at the root of WP installation ) :

```
<?php 
require_once( 'wp-load.php' );
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.domain.com/mytest.php' );
print $response ['body']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access your test.php file directly? If so, then WordPress won't be loaded, so `wp_remote_get()` won't work.

To use `wp_remote_get` you need to make sure WordPress is loaded. Try hooking into `wp_loaded`:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
  $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://example.com/' );
  print $response[ 'body' ];
} );
```

There's a chance your server is configured in such a way that the methods used by `wp_remote_get` are not available to WordPress. If that's the case, make sure curl or wget is installed on the server.